# ACPI Parameters

Tags: release-loki, kernel, acpi

So I bought an Acer Swift 3 very recently, but after a fresh install off Ubuntu, it couldn't boot without setting acpi to off. I tried installing elementaryOS instead -I wanted to give it a try for a long time-, but no luck. I still had to add `acpi=off` to boot options. However after some doing this and doing that, I installed kernel 4.10.1 and with it I could boot into OS. But during the booting I could see some really fast texts appearing at the background, giving some error messages. So my main questions are; how can I look at those boot logs, and how can I be sure if the OS is stable. Thanks already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `sudo journalctl` in a terminal will give you the system log from the last boot onwards, you can then scroll through using the arrow keys.